# Select appropriate data range for mixed model

Tags: r, regression, mixed-models

**Background:** I have the lmer model

```
lmer(log(log(Amplification)) ~ poly(Voltage, 3) + 
           (poly(Voltage, 3) | Serial_number), data = APD)
```

for a data frame APD. This contains lot of devices, separated by Serial_number. Each device's amplification was measured in the voltage range from 0 V to about 400 V. 
In total I have about 1500 devices (and nearly 80,000 observables).

**Motivation:** My goal is to get the corresponding voltage of a certain amplification for each device; Voltage(Amplification=150)?.
With the help of extracting the coefficients of the polynomials I'm able to do an inverse regression and to calculate this voltage.

**Problem:** When I select the data range in different ways I calculate different voltages. This is more or less reasonable because the fits vary. How can I ensure which voltage is correct?
When I take the whole data range the calculated (Amplification=150, Voltage(A=150))-point is far beside the measurement data.
When I limit the data range then the point moves closer and closer to the measurement data. So obviously I can influence that strongly by selecting the data range.

**Bottom line:** My very goal is to find the very most **reliable** voltage for each device having an amplification of Amplification=150.

The plots of the calculated data points:

Whole data range for fitting with lmer:

[image: Single device complete data range]

Limited data range with ignoring all measurement data below Amplification<100 and all higher than Amplification>200.

[image: Single device]

The origin curve of one single device:

[image: Single subset/Serial_number]

Minimal data set and script: https://files.fm/u/5yy22kkm

P.S: It's a [cross-post from here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/311406/selection-of-data-range-changes-coefficients-too-much-in-lmer-inverse-regressio), but the question has not attracted a lot of attention.

Comment: To help people who might read it in the future, would you add a declaration of cross-posting on the other post as well? That will save the time of folks who wish to post an answer there, who might be unaware that this post has attracted an answer in the meantime. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, I'll add it there!